# Having trouble adding objects to NSMutableArray in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I am using the iPhone SDK and have an issue doing something simple. I am trying to add an **NSNumber** object to an **NSMutableArray** instance variable. I tried adding NSNumber **card** to NSMutableArray **viewedCardsArray**, however without breaking, it does not get added to the array. Here is the code.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Inside the header file Class.h
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
   NSMutableArray *viewedCardsArray;
   //snip ...
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *viewedCardsArray;
@end

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Inside the methods file Class.m
#import "StudyViewController.h"

@implementation StudyViewController
@synthesize viewedCardsArray
  //snip ...

- (IBAction)doShowCard {
   //snip ...
   NSNumber *cardIdObject = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:(int)[self.currentCard cardId]];
   [viewedCardsArray addObject: cardIdObject];
   [cardIdObject release];
}
```

So this code executes, and does not seem to leak (according to the Leaks performance tool). However when stepping through the code, at no point does **CardIdObject** appear in **viewedCardsArray**.

Looking through SO, I know these basic questions are pretty common to ObjC newbies (like me) so apologies in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you initialized your `viewedCardsArray`? If not you need to somewhere - this is usually done in the `init` method for your class:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        viewedCardsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then it is released in the `dealloc` method:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [viewedCardsArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to use the result of [super init]. It can return nil or a different object. Never assume that it returned your former self, because when it doesn't, it released it, and any further initialization you do of that now-dead object will probably cause a crash. The simplest way is if ((self = [super init])) { /*initialize here*/ } return self; (subject to your own style taste—for example, you can have the assignment before the condition if you want).

Comment: Sorry I meant that line to be self = [super init]; but yes, that is a better approach

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone. I now appreciate the difference between a class declaration and instantiating a variable!

Comment: I had `myArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];` in my `init` method. However the child class wasn't calling `init`. It was calling `initWithStyle`. So my array initialization was not happening 8-)

Comment: This was my mistake as well. I assumed that having it in the header and synthesizing it initialized the object. Obviously not!

Answer (score 3):

Perspx has outlined one way of initializing the array. However, you can also use the class methods provided by NSArray:

```
self. viewedCardsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

This can go in init or elsewhere.

Note: The object will be autoreleased.

Comment: The problem with that is that when you set your own properties in -init, you're sending messages (specifically, accessor messages) to a not-fully-initialized object (self). The same is true in reverse in -dealloc. This can become a problem if you implement a custom accessor that assumes that some other ivar has already been initialized and that the object in it (if any) is still valid.

Comment: If you're using synthesized properties, this is a perfectly valid way of doing things. There's Apple code which does this, for example, as well as the inverse: using self.someProperty = nil in the -dealloc method.