# Adding items into a NSMutableArray property

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsarray, addition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Having trouble adding objects to NSMutableArray in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851926/having-trouble-adding-objects-to-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c)

I have a class with an NSMutabeArray property. In one of the class's methods, I am trying to add objects from another NSArray into this NSMutableArray. (The objects added are NSDictionaries). I have tried a couple of methods for this (specified below) but none of them seems t work, as the objects aren't added into the array (I can see that when I NSLog the count property of the NSMutableArray, which still returns 0.

Why is that, and what is the proper way of adding Items into an NSMutableArray?

Way 1:

```
NSArray * logItemsTemp = [logParsedData objectForKey:@"log"]; //items to add, NSlooged the count property and there are 3 items
[[self logItemsArray] addObjectsFromArray:logItemsTemp]; //adding items to the NSMutableArrayProperty logItems array - unsuccessful
```

Way 2:

```
NSArray * logItemsTemp = [logParsedData objectForKey:@"log"];  //items to add, NSlooged the count property and there are 3 items
for (int i = 0; i<[logItemsTemp count]; i++) {
      [logItemsArray addObject:[logItemsTemp objectAtIndex:i]]; //adding items to the NSMutableArrayProperty logItems array - unsuccessful
}
```

EDIT:

```
NSArray * logItemsTemp = [logParsedData objectForKey:@"log"];
    if ([self logItemsArray] == NULL) {
        self.logItemsArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        NSLog(@"%@",logItemsTemp);
    }
        [[self logItemsArray] addObjectsFromArray:logItemsTemp];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having trouble adding objects to NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/q/851926) [Cannot add items to an NSMutableArray ivar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7125326), [\[NSMutableArray addObject:\] not affecting count](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3683761), [\[NSMutableArray addObject:\] not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1827058)

Answer (score 1):

Either way works. The first way is more efficient.

The reason you're not adding anything is I think that you have forgotten to make your mutable array in the first place :)

You say that `self.logItemsArray.count` is 0. This might be becasuse `self.logItemsArray` is `nil` :)

```
// Let's see what my logitemsarray is
NSLog(@"%@", self.logItemsArray);
```

Comment: well it returns null, though I have declared it as a property in the header file and i have synthesised it...

Comment: All that just means that your object can have a mutable array, not that you have given it one :) Try something like `self.logItemsArray = [NSMutableArray new];`

Comment: Well I added the [NSMutableArray new] as you can see in the edit, but it still doesnt work....

Comment: Have you checked that `logItemsTemp` isn't `nil` or empty - `NSLog(@"%@", logItemsTemp);` ? That's the only other think I can think of.

Comment: I did it and that is what I got: (
        {
        amount = "100.00";
        date = "01/01/2000";
        recipient = "Sushi Shop Nice";
    },
        {
        amount = "12.00";
        date = "31/12/2011";
        recipient = "Fuxi Israel";
    },
        {
        amount = "48.00";
        date = "21/12/1997";
        recipient = "Rambam Hospital Taxi";
    }
)