# Objective C Creating a search for string in array of strings

Tags: objective-c, ios, search, nsmutablearray, nsarray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSMutableArray addObject not affecting count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683761/nsmutablearray-addobject-not-affecting-count)

I'm creating a search function that searches the NSArray `catalogArray` for any instance of a particular string defined in `searchMe.text`. Once a match is discovered, I'd like to add the objects to the mutable array `searchResultMA`, but so far I get null results.

Here's my search method:

```
-(IBAction)searchFor{
    int i=0;
    for (int j=0; j<[catalogMA count]/170; j++) {
        NSRange rangeArray = NSMakeRange(j*170, 170);
        catalogArray = [catalogMA subarrayWithRange:rangeArray];
        if([catalogArray containsObject:searchMe.text]) {
            NSLog(@"catalogArray count=%d", [catalogArray count]);
            [searchResultMA addObjectsFromArray:catalogArray];
            NSLog(@"%d, %@", i, [searchResultMA objectAtIndex:9+i*170]);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

and, here is my console output when I search for a string that I know has two instances in the array:

```
2013-01-08 18:07:05.300 Catalog[3229:c07] catalogArray count=170
2013-01-08 18:07:05.301 Catalog[3229:c07] 0, (null)
2013-01-08 18:07:05.301 Catalog[3229:c07] catalogArray count=170
2013-01-08 18:07:05.302 Catalog[3229:c07] 1, (null)
```

Why do I get a `(null)` result from `searchResultsMA`?

When I add in the line `NSLog(@"%d, %d", i, [searchResultMA count]);` within the conditional, I get `0,0` and `1,0`, which tells me that there's nothing in the `searchResultMA` mutable array. It was supposed to be `0,170` and `1,340`. Thoughts? Tips? Suggestions? All welcome...

Comment: `searchResultsMA` is `nil`. You need to create it. Possible duplicate of [Having trouble adding objects to NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/q/851926) [Cannot add items to an NSMutableArray ivar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7125326), [\[NSMutableArray addObject:\] not affecting count](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3683761), [\[NSMutableArray addObject:\] not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1827058)

Comment: Brilliant Josh! Duh. That's it exactly. Thanks a lot.