# Why is my object nil when I get it from a NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm having a problem with this code here

```
Book *theNewBook = [self parseTheBookXML];
// The book is not nil here
NSLog(@"The book's title: %@, number of pages:%@ and author: %@",theNewBook.title, theNewBook.pages, theNewBook.author);

[_theBooksArray addObject:theNewBook];

// TEST
Book *testBook = [_theBooksArray objectAtIndex:0];
// The book is nil here
NSLog(@"The book's title: %@, number of pages:%@ and author: %@",testBook.title, testBook.pages, testBook.author);
```

Can anyone tell me why my book object is 'nil' because I've hit a wall over here...

Comment: check whether _theBookArray is nil or not ?

Comment: Probably because `__theBooksArray` is `nil`.

Comment: ditto, maybe you never initialized the array itself.

Comment: Thanks, sry for the stupid question. The array was never initialized alright...:/

Comment: Best way to check stuff like this always is to Log you Array: NSLog(@"Array: %@",_theBooksArray);

Comment: @Filip : you can write your answer here in Answer section :)

Comment: @Filip Or don't bother as it's been seen thousands of times before.

Comment: I hate when that happens - forgot to initialize something - I wish future programming languages will initialize the variable for you before hand. If I define a array you bet I wanna use it so ... initialize it by default!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having trouble adding objects to NSMutableArray in Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851926/having-trouble-adding-objects-to-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the comments on my question my problem was that I had not initialized the array I was accessing. So INSTEAD of

```
[_theBooksArray addObject:theNewBook];
```

calling

```
_theBooksArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:theNewBook, nil];
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
[_theBooksArray addObject:theNewBook];
[_theBooksArray count];
```

print the log and check the array count.

Comment: The OP already solved the problem by checking if the array was initialized.

Comment: @AKV At the time of writing, he has 2 downvotes and 1 upvote, so he would lose 6 points if he deleted his answer.

Comment: @trojanfoe :p   I like downvotes more than up votes, but there should a comment with that. from past 15 days.... i m gettng downvotes without any comment. Even I cant know who is downvoting me 3-5 times everyday. :(

Answer (score 0):

You Must Init The Array Before Using it.

_theBooksArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];