# NSMutableArray not adding object

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I keep trying to get my array count but it keeps returning 0, i think its not adding the object correctly. I Put my property in header file and synthesized it in the layer.m file. i allocated space in my super init.

```
NSMutableArray *asteroids;

@property (strong) NSMutableArray *asteroids;

@synthesize asteroids;

self.asteroids = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

-(void)findTiles
{
    CGPoint tilecoord1;
    int tileGid1;
    int aheadcount = 200;
    CCSprite *tileonPos[aheadcount];
    int amounts = 0;

    for(int x = 0; x<30; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y<20; y++)
        {
            tilecoord1 = ccp(x+(480*currentlevel),y);
            tileGid1 = [bglayer tileGIDAt:tilecoord1];
            if(tileGid1 == 1)
            {
                tileonPos[amounts] = [bglayer tileAt:ccp(x,y)];
                amounts++;
                [asteroids addObject:tileonPos[amounts]];
                NSLog(@"%d",[asteroids count]);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check first if this code passes the if statement. `tileGid1 == 1` might never evaluate to TRUE (YES). I assume that you have separated the definition and the initiation!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having trouble adding objects to NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/q/851926) [Cannot add items to an NSMutableArray ivar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7125326), [\[NSMutableArray addObject:\] not affecting count](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3683761), [\[NSMutableArray addObject:\] not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1827058)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever method you're initializing `asteroids` in either isn't run when `findTiles` is or isn't run at all.  Without more information, it's impossible to say more, but that's almost certainly what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

when you init you called `self.asteroids = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` but when you adding you call `[asteroids addObject:tileonPos[amounts]];`.

try: `[self.asteroids addObject:tileonPos[amounts]];` or `[_asteroids addObject:tileonPos[amounts]];`

also are you sure the `self.asteroids = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` is executed in init?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only going to add objects to "asteroids" in findTiles method, try initializing the array in that method before for loop .

```
self.asteroids = [@[] mutableCopy];
```