# NSMutableArray not letting me access object?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I am extremely new to objective-c and iPhone programming (although, i have a little more background with C#), and I am learning by doing.

I am currently trying to make a mini platform game and instead of checking each platform on its own to see if my player intersects with it, I want to make an array and a for statement which will take care of that. (Correct me if i am wrong but `NSMutableArray` seems a lot like the `List` feature in C#)

I typed what i think would work but it hasn't, any ideas why? In my `@interface` I have:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *platforms;
    UIImageView *platform1;
    UIImageView *platform2;
    UIImageView *platform3;
    UIImageView *platform4;
    UIImageView *platform5;
    UIImageView *player;
}

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger GameState;
@property IBOutlet UIImageView *player;
@property IBOutlet UIImageView *platform1;
@property IBOutlet UIImageView *platform2;
@property IBOutlet UIImageView *platform3;
@property IBOutlet UIImageView *platform4;
@property IBOutlet UIImageView *platform5;
```

And in my @implementation i have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/60 target:self selector:@selector(gameLoop) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    gravity = CGPointMake(0,0.195);
    [platforms addObject:platform1];
    [platforms addObject:platform2];
    [platforms addObject:platform3];
    [platforms addObject:platform4];
    [platforms addObject:platform5];
}

- (void)gameLoop
{
    playerVelocity = CGPointMake(playerVelocity.x,playerVelocity.y + gravity.y);
    player.center = CGPointMake(player.center.x + playerVelocity.x,player.center.y + playerVelocity.y);
    for(UIImageView *platform in platforms)
    {
        if(CGRectIntersectsRect(platform.frame,player.frame))
        {
           BOOL check = YES; //break point here to check if it reaches this point
        }
    }    
}
```

Also, when i simply type:

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(platform1.frame,player.frame))
{
    BOOL doubleCHECK = YES;
}
```

It works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having trouble adding objects to NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/q/851926) [Cannot add items to an NSMutableArray ivar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7125326), [\[NSMutableArray addObject:\] not affecting count](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3683761), [\[NSMutableArray addObject:\] not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1827058)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You failed to allocate your platforms array.  All objects in objective-c are pointers, therefore, probably in your `viewDidLoad` method, you need a line of code like this:

```
platforms = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check `platforms` before the loop, I believe you will find that it is `nil`. You need to create it before you use it (`viewDidLoad` is probably the best place, unless you need it before the view is loaded) - and unlike some languages, operating on a null object will silently return 0, not throw an exception.