# Efficiently register multiple observes to a notification

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm writing an iOS game with a bunch of different types of enemies and items/drops. Specific ones need to trigger things on different events, so I'm experimenting with using NSNotificationCenter.

Everything works when `listener` is defined in a way that's retained. When I define it locally or add it to an `NSMutableArray`, it's lost and the `postNotification` throws a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

This breaks, because the `listener` isn't retained past this.

```
MyListener *listener = [[MyListener alloc] init];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:listener selector:@selector(myEventHandler:) name:@"MyEvent" object:nil];
```

This is a super basic example of what works:

```
MyListener *listener;
-(id)init {
    listener = [[MyListener alloc] init];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:listener selector:@selector(myEventHandler:) name:@"MyEvent" object:nil];
}
```

The issue is that I will have a bunch of different enemy/item classes that need to listen for an event. I don't want a different class-level variable for every single one - but admit that I may be going about this the wrong way. I'm still somewhat new to iOS.

Comment: As you've seen, you need to keep a strong reference to the observer. How that is done depends on your needs. There's not enough enough here to offer any real suggestions.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to create an object just to serve as an observer of a notification. If an object didn't have another reason to exist (which would mean something else was keeping a strong reference to it), then why does it care about the notification? The objects representing the "enemies and items/drops" should be the observers of the notification.

Comment: If you don't mind runtime tricks, here's a KVO helper I made that I find useful: https://github.com/nielsbot/kvo-helper It automatically deregisters when the observed object is deallocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, your `init` snippet is entirely wrong.  `init` methods should look more like this:

```
- (instancetype) {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // initialize
    }
    return self;
}
```

And in your example, `// initialize` would be replaced with:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(myEventHandler:) 
                                             name:@"MyEvent" 
                                           object:nil];
```

But what's most important here is that at some point before this object is completely deallocated, we must stop observing.  If we do not, after this object is deallocated, `NSNotificationCenter` will try to send a message to a deallocated object, which causes your `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

You may wish to stop observing earlier than dealloc, but at a minimum, you need to add this to your class:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

---

As for keeping the object alive, well that's as simple as keeping a strong reference to it.  This is sort of an entirely different question.  Although... if you're trying to keep an object alive simply to respond to a notification, there's no need to even use an object here.

You can give the notification center a block to respond to notification with using the following method:

```
- (id)addObserverForName:(NSString *)name
                  object:(id)obj 
                   queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue 
              usingBlock:(void (^)(NSNotification *))block
```

Comment: My init was more psuedocode, so you're correct that it's missing stuff. The problem I have is that these classes need to listen for an unknown length of time. Something has to store the reference to each object listening. I found that adding them all to an `NSMutableArray` doesn't work.

Comment: It's not that your `init` was missing stuff.  It was poorly formed.

Comment: Using the block may be the solution for me - it's only a little bit of code for every class that needs it

Comment: An `NSArray` has a strong reference to each of its members, @helion3, so there's no reason that should not be working -- something needs to own the array itself, too, though.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then, because even though my object is in an array, it still throws the access error. This is essentially how I'm handling it: https://pste.me/#/VxpEQ

Comment: @helion: [Having trouble adding objects to NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/q/851926)